# Why is $f(n) = n - 1$ an onto function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking discrete math and I don't understand why $f(n) = n - 1$ is an onto function. From my knowledge, onto functions return the same answer from two or more numbers. So why is $f(n) = n - 1$ onto?

Comment: That's not the definition of an onto function.  $f$ is onto a set $S$ if $f$ assumes every value in $S$ at least once.

Comment: " From my knowledge, onto functions return the same answer from two or more numbers."  That is not at all correct.  Onto $\ne$ not one-to-one.... An  onto function is one in which every possible value *is* mapped to (none are left out).  For any $m$ then $m$ is mapped to from $m+1$.   $f(m+1) = (m+1)-1 = m$.  So every element *is* mapped to and $f$ is onto.

Comment: $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Okay, Thank you. That makes a bit more sense. So, f(n) = n - 1 is onto, would that also make f(n) = n + 1 an onto function?

Comment: What's your domain and co-domain?  I'm a little concerned because if $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ then $f(1)$ is not actually defined because $1-1 =0\not \in \mathbb N$.  So $f(n) = n-1$ is not actually a function from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ at all.  But it is an onto function from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.  Or from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  $f(n) = n+1$ is an onto function for $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  But it is *not* an onto function for $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ because $f(n) =1$ has no solution.  $0 \not \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: The book has from Z -> Z.

Comment: That's fine then.  $f(n) = n-1$ and $f(n)= n+1$ are both onto and they are both one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing "onto" with "not one-to-one", I guess.  A function can be onto, one-to-one, both, or neither.

Onto means that if $f: A\to B$ then every element of $B$ gets mapped to at least once.  i.e.  For every $m \in B$ there is at least one  $n\in A$ so that $f(n) = m$.

So for any $m$ we can get $f(n) =m$ if $m = n-1$ or in other words if $n = m+1$.  So to get $f(n) =m$ we do $f(m+1)= (m+1)-1 = m$.  We can do that for every possible value of $m$.

So that is the definition of "onto".  That there is *only* one such value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to say that the function $f(n)=n-1$ is onto because for every $n$, it assumes different values and every value of the codomain has a different controimage in the domain.